# タスクバー上のEmEditorアイコンから、ピン留めしたファイルを開いた時、そのファイルが既に開かれていた時にアクティブにならない件

Tags: emeditor

Windows 10でEmEditor 20.0.901を使っている者です。

タスクバーにEmEditorをピン留めしてあり、頻繁に使うファイルについては、そのEmEditorアイコンを右クリックした時に立ち上がるメニューの中に、ピン留めしてあります。

それで、ふと気がついたのですが、例えば、A.TXTというファイルをこのようにピン留めしてあったとして、このファイルを既にEmEditorで開いていたとします。しかもそのファイルは表には見えていなくて、すなわちアクティブではなくて、裏の方で開いていたとします。

この時、タスクバー上のEmEditorアイコンを右クリックした時に立ち上がるメニューの中にピン留めしたA.TXTを選択した時、以前でしたら、A.TXTは表に出てきた、すなわちアクティブになったような気がするのですが、現在のところ、このように選択しても、何も起こりません。すなわち裏に隠れたままになっています。

これは是非、アクティブになって欲しいところなのですが、オプションか何かで設定できるものなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

この問題は v20.0.902 で修正しています。最新版に更新してください。

Comment: 更新チェッカーで最新版であることを確かめてはいたのですが、「更新チャネルの選択」でベータ版もインストールできるようになっているのですね。初めて知りました。お陰様で、バージョンは20.0.904となり、問題は解決しました。ありがとうございます。